# Como hago para crear un bucle que recorra cada carácter de una palabra que se encuentra en la línea 1 de un txt en batch

Tags: batch

Hola buenas me estoy creando un login y registro en .bat y soy nuevo en el código , tengo 2 archivos : un login.bat y un register.bat , ahora estoy haciendo un encryptor.bat que se pase despues del set/p que pide el usuario y contraseña al usuario , que porcierto estos dos se almacenan en un txt . Sé como hacer un programa que encripte un texto de un txt pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer un programa que me permita ir recorriendo cada letra para cambiarlo por un conjunto de letras o por la variable %random% .

Si alguien me responde se lo agradecería, y si ademas me diera informacion de cada comando y de todo se lo agradeceria mucho más .

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué fue lo que intentaste hasta el momento? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir recorriendo las letra implementando este código

fichero.bat

```
   @ECHO OFF
   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   :inicio
   cls
   SET /P "TEXTO=Introduce el texto a recorrer="
   CALL :RECORRER_TEXTO_INICIO "%TEXTO%"
   TIMEOUT /T 5
   GOTO inicio
   
   :RECORRER_TEXTO_INICIO
   SET "TEXTO_ENTERO=%~1"
   
   :RECORRER_TEXTO_BUCLE
   (FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%R IN ("!TEXTO_ENTERO!") DO ( 
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%L IN ("!TEXTO_ENTERO:~0,1!") DO (
        ECHO Letra = '%%L'
        REM PUEDES INCLUIR TU CODIGO AQUI %%L ES LA LETRA QUE SE VA RECORRIENDO 
        REM SENTENCIA 1 
        REM SENTENCIA 2 
        REM SENTENCIA 3+
        
        SET "TEXTO_ENTERO=%TEXTO_ENTERO:~1%"
        GOTO :RECORRER_TEXTO_BUCLE 
    )
   ))||ECHO TERMINADO&GOTO :eof
```